# How to send and receive SMS from python using usb modem?

Tags: python, sms, at-command, gammu

I'm a beginner in python and i'm looking for a library to send and receive SMS through a Huawei modem. I tried gammu, pysms and pygsm but failed to get them to work. Could you give me code examples with those libraries?

Comment: Try this: https://code.google.com/p/pyhumod/

Comment: Not sure why this is quite useful indeed!! upvote by me (and several other 'future' come present users!!!!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code, it works for me , just plug your USB dongle and get it's device node path(in linux use lsusb and ls -lha /dev/tty*) and replace `/dev/ttyACM0` with that path.Then you should able to send sms, This code works for me with Huawei USB modem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
sms.py - Used to send txt messages.
"""
import serial
import time

class TextMessage:
    def __init__(self, recipient="0123456789", message="TextMessage.content not set."):
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.content = message

    def setRecipient(self, number):
        self.recipient = number

    def setContent(self, message):
        self.content = message

    def connectPhone(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 460800, timeout=5)
        time.sleep(1)

    def sendMessage(self):
        self.ser.write('ATZ\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('AT+CMGF=1\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write('''AT+CMGS="''' + self.recipient + '''"\r''')
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(self.content + "\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ser.write(chr(26))
        time.sleep(1)

    def disconnectPhone(self):
        self.ser.close()
```

for more details try this [link](http://linux-101.org/script/python-code-sending-sms-messages-usb-connected-mobile-phone) ([archive of that dead link as of 2014-08-25](https://web.archive.org/web/20140825120353/http://linux-101.org/script/python-code-sending-sms-messages-usb-connected-mobile-phone) )

Comment: link not working, without it, this answer is usless

Comment: Thanks for sharing python serial send text.  If not work,  just custome AT Command. Refer to GSM Modem.